# Multiple counts in a multi table query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, relational-database

I would like to count The different requests by survey Id's and grouping it by SubjectValue

I have done this on just the one table with a sub query, but I'm not too sure to do it with several. Could anyone help me out?

This is how the 3 tables are joined. The only values of note are

```
subjectValue - Table A
Request_Id - Table A
Survey_Id - Table C
```

```
SELECT     TableA.SubjectValue
FROM          TableB INNER JOIN
                       TableA ON TableB.ID = TableA.Request_ID INNER JOIN
                       Table C ON TableB.Details_ID = TableC.ID
```

May I also add that all counts should be returned in the same row.

there are 3 different survey Id's so the count will need a where clause on the survey_id.

Hope that makes sense.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generic Cross-tab method

```
select 
    TableA.SubjectValue,
    SUM(case when somecol='request1' then 1 else 0 end) as request1,
    SUM(case when somecol='request2' then 1 else 0 end) as request2,
    .
TableB INNER JOIN
                       TableA ON TableB.ID = TableA.Request_ID INNER JOIN
                       Table C ON TableB.Details_ID = TableC.ID
group by
    TableA.SubjectValue
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably dont need to join to table C (surveys) assuming you have a foreign key to it on table B (Requests).

try this.

```
SELECT TableA.SubjectValue, COUNT(TableB.SurveyID)
FROM TableB 
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableB.ID = TableA.Request_ID 
Group by TableA.SubjectValue
```

EDIT: To Include SurveyID use this..

```
SELECT      TableC.SurveyID, TableA.SubjectValue, COUNT(TableB.RequestId)
FROM        TableA 
INNER JOIN  TableB ON TableB.SurveyID = TableA.SurveyID 
INNER JOIN  TableC ON TableC.RequestID = TableB.RequestID
Group by TableA.SubjectValue, TableC.SurveyID
```

(hope i didnt get my A, B's and C's mixed up.)

Comment: I need to include the survey Id. It's the only way to distinguish the different types of surveys.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to put in my original question that the counts for each survey Id should all be returned in the same grouped row.